# Store code output in a dataframe instead of only `print`

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: Pic1.jpg]

I have a code that extracts dominant colors from an image. Currently, the output of the code consists in:

- a plot (not shown)
- this print: `Dominant colors: gray maroon silver gray black`

In addition, I would also like this output to be stored in a single-column dataframe whose column would be named "Colors".

The desired output would look like this (made by hand for the occasion):

```
data = { 'Colors' : [ 'gray', 'maroon', 'silver', 'gray', 'black']}
frame = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Here is the full code where I am trying to create the dataframe of the output.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import webcolors
from webcolors import HTML4_HEX_TO_NAMES, hex_to_rgb

image_path = "Pic1.jpg"
num_colors = 5
num_clusters = 5

def get_dominant_colors(image_path, num_colors=10, num_clusters=5):
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    image = image.resize((200, 200))
    image = image.convert('RGB')
    img_array = np.array(image)
    pixels = img_array.reshape(-1, 3)
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters, random_state=0)
    labels = kmeans.fit_predict(pixels)
    centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_
    color_counts = {}
    for label in np.unique(labels):
        color = tuple(centers[label].astype(int))
        color_counts[color] = np.count_nonzero(labels == label)
    sorted_colors = sorted(color_counts.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    dominant_colors = [color for color, count in sorted_colors[:num_colors]]
    color_occurrences = [count for color, count in sorted_colors[:num_colors]]
    dominant_colors_hex = ['#%02x%02x%02x' % color for color in dominant_colors]
    return dominant_colors_hex, color_occurrences

dominant_colors, color_occurrences = get_dominant_colors(image_path, num_colors, num_clusters)

def closest_color(hex):
    colors = {}
    for key, name in HTML4_HEX_TO_NAMES.items():
        r_c, g_c, b_c = hex_to_rgb(key)
        rd = (int(hex[1:3], 16) - r_c) ** 2
        gd = (int(hex[3:5], 16) - g_c) ** 2
        bd = (int(hex[5:7], 16) - b_c) ** 2
        colors[(rd + gd + bd)] = name
    return colors[min(colors.keys())]
print("Dominant colors: ")

for col in dominant_colors:
    col_name = closest_color(col)
    print(col_name)

palette_height = 100
palette_width = 100 * num_colors
palette = np.zeros((palette_height, palette_width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

start_x = 0
for color_hex in dominant_colors:
    color_rgb = tuple(int(color_hex[i:i+2], 16) for i in (1, 3, 5))
    end_x = start_x + 100
    palette[:, start_x:end_x] = color_rgb
    start_x = end_x

palette_image = Image.fromarray(palette)
palette_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(palette_image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

cv2.imshow("Palette", palette_bgr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hello, it seems you have summarized your question in the first lines of your post. Is the full code relevant at all for your problem? If not, in the spirit of [mre], please remove it. Instead, please make it better stand out what object `Dominant colors: gray maroon silver gray black` is. We should not have to decipher your full code to deduce that information. Is this a string, and is your question, how to extract sub-strings into a new dataframe? Finally, tags machine-leaerning and image-processing do not fit in here. This is solely about instanciating a new dataframe.

Comment: Hi, the full code is relevant. If you run the full code in jupyter notebook with the attached image, you will get the output "Dominant colors: gray maroon silver gray black". I don't want only the output like this. I want the output as a DF. So even if I use 100 images, it will be all sorted in a DF in a column called "colors". So that's why I've provided the full code, because I am not be able to add this part to my full code. Been trying it since Saturday.

Comment: it's purely a pandas question. the way you calculate that data is irrelevant. you have it and you want to put it into an... excel file? csv? what? "dataframe" is a class of pandas, purely an object at runtime. it's not storage.

Comment: I think you're too advanced in this and thinking too complicated. It's very simple; i want the outcome of this code in a dataframe (or call it a table?) that includes columns and rows. Right now, the code gives me a blank output "gray maroon silver gray black". I want it in a dataframe on the first row as 1. gray, maroon silver gray black. So

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77282731/create-a-table-of-the-extracted-values-from-image and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77283664/extract-capacity-values-from-an-image

Comment: answer available

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with [`str` methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).

Steps:

1. Split once at ":"
2. Select " gray maroon silver gray black" and strip extra whitespaces
3. Split at whitespace

```py
color_str = "Dominant colors: gray maroon silver gray black"
color_list = color_str.split(":", maxsplit=1)[1].strip().split(" ")
data = {"Colors": color_list}
print(data)
```

Comment: Thank you. But I wanted a different outcome. So in my question you can see this long code starting from "import cv2" and ending with "cv2.destroyAllWindows()". If you run this long code in jupyter notebook and use the attached image called "Pic1" it it will give you the output "Dominant colors: gray maroon silver gray black". But I don't want the output to be like this. because I will be using multiple images as input. I want the input to be in a DF. Did you get it?

Answer (score 0):

**About your code**

It looks like the output you are talking about results is a print resulting from this section in the middle of your code:

```py
print("Dominant colors: ")

for col in dominant_colors:
    col_name = closest_color(col)
    print(col_name)
```

(The remainder of the code is about crafting a plot, so, talking about MRE, that next bit could be safely removed from the post.)

And images analyses are going to pile up, so naturally you would like this automatically added to a repository dataframe, OK.

---

**Suggestion**

Insert this after the print loop:

```
df_img = pd.DataFrame({image_path : [closest_color(col) for col in dominant_colors]})
```

- Notice the column is not named "Colors" as you requested, but after the picture's file path instead. Somehow you must document the source of the data (expecting many pictures to be added next to it) and this is a convenient way to do it. If the file path is too long, and it does not lead to ambiguity with other files, it may be reduced to its mere file name, as in [os.path.basename(path)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html)
- This dataframe for a single picture can later be appended to a repository dataframe like this:

  Repo = pd.concat([*your list of dataframes*], axis=1)

Now when do other pictures analyses come around? Same notebook? Different session, requiring export to file on harddrive? This we cannot guess.